# 404 error page redirection

Tags: subdomain, http-status-code-404, custom-error-pages

I've setup a custom 404 error page using the following code.

```
 ErrorDocument 400 /errors.php
```

But when I check the headers sent i see that first a 301 moved permanently is sent followed by a 404 error header. So is it good for seo will it create problem with bots.

My second question is reg. transfer of non-existent sub-domains to 404 error pages.I'm using Cpanel and i want only the subdomains created in CPanel to work and i've created a wildcard redirect but non existent subdomain gives me a OK status.How do i redirect it to 404 page.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

googlebot-news has special requirements published recently, like they won't acept old site schema-s any more

Comment: So may i know what is the problem with this code and how to correct it.